# Need Help Getting WiFi to Work on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Install Broadcom / STA Wireless card (BCM43XX)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-sta-wireless-card-bcm43xx)

I'm having trouble connecting to my home's wifi network, i've run the `sudo lshw -C` network command, and since I'm on another computer I can't type it all out but here's some info:

```
*-network  
description:Network controller  
product: BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY  
vendor: broadcom corporation
```

If any info is needed, ask, and I'll gladly provide it. I also noticed that under Additional Drivers in Settings, there's a Broadcom STA wireless driver that I can activate however when I click activate I get an error that says that the installation has failed. And I'm provided with a log file location to look at for details but I'm unsure of where to look for that path. How can I get connected to my network?

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx?action=show&redirect=WifiDocs%2FDriver%2FBroadcom43xx

Check that page. In this case, Broadcom 4312 is supported by both b43 and wl.
Make sure to run `sudo apt-get update` and then try to `sudo apt-get --reinstall install bcmwl-kernel-source` and tell me what happens in the command line. If it doens't work, you can also try `sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source` followed by `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer` to install the reverse-engineered b43 driver instead of the closed-source broadcom bcmwl module.